# Open media box library from link

Tags: plugin-development, media-library

I am developing a plugin in which I want to open media library box after clicking on a link from Admin Panel just like we do for Choose featured image.

```
<a href="#">Choose Image</a>
```

After clicking on Choose Image I want that media library box displayed in thickbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enqueuing an JS file, we can do it like this:

```
<img src="#" id="img-src">
<a href="#" id="img-upload">Add Image</a>
```

**Content of JS file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#img-upload').click(function(){
        var upload = wp.media({
        title:'Choose Image', //Title for Media Box
        multiple:false //For limiting multiple image
        })
        .on('select', function(){
            var select = upload.state().get('selection');
            var attach = select.first().toJSON();
            console.log(attach.id); //the attachment id of image
            console.log(attach.url); //url of image
            jQuery('img#img-upload').attr('src',attach.url);
        })
        .open();
   });

});
```

Like this we can have it.

Answer (score -2):

```
<img src="#" id="img-src"><a href="#" id="img-upload">Add Image</a>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#img-upload').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var upload = wp.media({
        title:'Choose Image', //Title for Media Box
        multiple:false //For limiting multiple image
        })
        .on('select', function(){
            var select = upload.state().get('selection');
            var attach = select.first().toJSON();
            console.log(attach.id); //the attachment id of image
            console.log(attach.url); //url of image
            jQuery('img#img-upload').attr('src',attach.url);
        })
        .open();
   });
});
```

wp_enqueue_media(); calls the scripts into the footer of the page.